# Firebase Google Sigin Authentication failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am Using this Code for sigin using Firebase.

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication Went wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        //updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });

}
```

}
But its giving Error when I am trying to sign in.Like Authentication failed .
Where i am doing it wrong ??

I have included both the dependencies for firebaseAuth Inside my app Gradle
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'`
And also enabled Google as SignIn method in my Firebase Console.

In my `logout.class` i am using this code` button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

```
    mAuthlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(logout.this, SignIn.class));
            }
        }
    };

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
        }
    });
}`
```

But when I click it then this Opens the `Sigin.class` but it crashes when we try to Sigin Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have used added SHA1 certificate to your Firebase project while creating Firebase project in the Firebase console and try to use my below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/back"

    tools:context="com.food.sheenishere.stark.MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/googlebtn"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"


        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


package com.food.sheenishere.stark;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SignInButton mGoogleBtn;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN=1;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final String TAG="MAINACTIVITY";
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // A progress dialog to display when the user is connecting in
    // case there is a delay in any of the dialogs being ready.
    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,profilemain.class));
                }
            }
        };
        mGoogleBtn=(SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googlebtn);

        // Configure the ProgressDialog that will be shown if there is a
        // delay in presenting the user with the next sign in step.
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"you got an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
        .build();

        mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void   firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                           mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                          //  updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           // updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Do let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Ok i will let you know

Comment: Worked As I connected Firebase to Android Studio From Tools Option, btw Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: One more thing I am Facing issues with the Logout button When User Can you Can you Suggest me a method. I had added my log out code above. Please check

Comment: i have posted another answer with signout code but i am using bottomnavigation layout in this. do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

for LOgOUt
you must the BottomNavigation layout as i have done in my project.and here below is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.food.sheenishere.stark.profilemain">



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the Java code.

```
package com.food.sheenishere.stark;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class profilemain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;





    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:

                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_signout:

                    Toast.makeText(profilemain.this, "You have successfully Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profilemain);





        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new
                            Intent(profilemain.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```